# Is it possible to redirect an SSL request to a specific IP address for load balancing?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

I'm would like to dynamically load balance SSL requests between a number of different servers. The thing that makes my situation complicated is that the bottle-necked resource is bandwidth rather than memory, CPU, etc. This means that any sort of proxy-based load balancing wouldn't really help. Is it possible for a DNS record to point to a single server which then redirects requests to other servers in a dynamic way? Something like this would be trivial over standard HTTP, but this isn't possible here due to mixed content limitations in browsers. It would be no problem at all to provide valid SSL certificates for the domain to all of the servers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with HTTPS the same way as with HTTP as long as all of the target servers have a valid certificate for the target domain from the redirect. If you control the DNS of the domain another option is to use [DNS based load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS), i.e. have multiple IP addresses (with different servers behind this address) for the same domain and rotate these whenever your DNS answers a new DNS request for the domain.

Comment: I'm aware of DNS based load balancing, but I'm hoping to have a solution that scales on a much shorter timescale than would be possible there. Could you elaborate on how you would handle the redirects over HTTPS? Would this be a 307? How do you specify the IP address while retaining the host name?

Comment: @Ivanna: The HTTP status code within HTTPS is the same as what would you use with plain HTTP, i.e. it depends on what you are trying to achieve. But 307 is probably fine since it is a temporary redirect. And like I said you can only redirect to a target where you have a matching certificate - which means you can probably not redirect to some IP address since you will not get a public certificate for an IP address. Instead you need to redirect to a different hostname, i.e. `www1.example.com`, `www2.example.com` etc

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible then. I was hoping to load balance to different IPs without changing the domain name.